# os.tempnam() fails creating temp files in c:/windows/temp

Tags: python, python-2.7, temp

With Python 2.7 (Windows 7), I create temporary files by using os.tempname().

The `os.tempnam()` fails with the following error :

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Windows\\TEMP\\200'
```

This brings two questions :

- The user executing the script being a local administrator and having full access to `c:/windows/temp`, why on earth is it unable to create the file ? (that very same user can create the file manually through Explorer) ?
- Both TEMP and TMP are defined for the user's environment variables and point to `c:/Users.../AppData/local/temp` directory (the system's TEMP and TMP point to `c:/Windows/temp`). But the `tempnam()` call keeps using `c:/windows/temp`. Why ?

In this case, I'd expect the `c:/Users.../AppData/local/temp` to be used, instead of c:/windows/temp (even though, in this case `c:/windows/temp` shall work).

Any idea ?

Comment: `os.tempnam()` *doesn't create files*, and therefore couldn't possibly have produced that error.  What are you actually doing with the return value from the function?

Comment: You are right. I pass that folder name a to a custom method using it to output an uncrypted file, based on a encrypted file (located in an existing custom directory). On the end, the method called to create the file is oOutFile = file(sOutFile, 'wb'), where sOutFile is probably C:\windows\temp\200 (probably, because I can not reproduce the issue on any Win10 or Win Vista machine, so hard to tell!)